# Java swing & sqlite - update image

Tags: java, swing, sqlite

I have a small problem with a Java Swing app and SQLite database. Every time, when I try to update the selected row from the table with an update button, my application, stored image for selected row in database delete from database.

My delete function:

```
String sql = "UPDATE PLAYER SET  NAME =? , LAST=?, DOB=?,   IMAGE=?, GENDER=?, LAST_UPDATE=?   WHERE  ID_PLAYER=? ";

Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
int id = Integer.parseInt(tf_id.getText());

try {
    pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    pst.setString(1, tf_name.getText());
    pst.setString(2, tf_last.getText());

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault());
    String d = sdf.format(t_date.getDate());
    pst.setString(3, d);

    pst.setBytes(4, person_image);

    if (combobox_male.isSelected()) {
        gender = "MAN";
    } else if (combobox_female.isSelected()) {
        gender = "WOMAN";
    }
    pst.setString(5, gender);

    pst.setTimestamp(6, timestamp);

    pst.setInt(7, id);
    pst.executeUpdate();
} catch (Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}
```

My Attach Image function:

```
JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser();
jfc.showOpenDialog(null);
File f = jfc.getSelectedFile();
filename = f.getAbsolutePath();
tetxfield_attach_image.setText(filename);
lable_picture.setIcon(ResizeImage(filename, null));
try {
    File image = new File(filename);
    FileImageInputStream fis = new FileImageInputStream(image);
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
    for (int readNum; (readNum = fis.read(buff)) != -1;) {
        bos.write(buff, 0, readNum);
    }
    person_image = bos.toByteArray();
} catch (Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Sorry, but it's impossible to understand this : "my application, stored image for selected row in database delete from database."

Comment: What is your problem ? The Update query delete the line ?

Comment: Significant clarification of the actual problem would be useful.

Comment: Sorry for late respon. First my mistake in original question. Not delete function but update function. This is the scenario. I have one jTable in my jFrame with players info (name, last name, date of birth, gender, ...) and I need to update info for specific player. When i click on table row,  data from table  are shown in TextField and when i click UPDATE button (no new data) everything is ok,  except image. Update statement delete saved image from database . Hope you understand what is my problem.Sorry for    spelling mistake

Answer (score 0):

Check if person_image get properly initiated before setting it to pst?  You mentioned there is no new data so it seems the initiating is the only chance to lose the image bytes.

Comment: Thx world for help, my problem is solved with some additional code. I added separately code for image in my update button event.  
1. Select statement only for image;                                                            2. Then selected image located into Label  for image;                                3. Update statement only for image (+ selected id of players).                            Best regards, Caks